# Creating an instance of a class and at the same time create an instance of another class that depends on the first class

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

EDIT:How is this question different from the one linked?

I think this question is different because it seems as if it is caused by JPA trying to add another user with the same id, because of a foregin key value in the class (Student) being added. The issue linked seems to be caused by not generateing the ids automatically.

I have a method that creates a User and returns a User. I pass this User to another method to create a Student. The user is a student. But I can't do this because I get :
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_user_id"
  Detail: Key (user_id)=(7001) already exists.

My methods in the backing bean looks like this:

```
public Users2 addUser(String username, String password, String emailadress, 
    String firstname, String lastname) {

    Users2 u = new Users2();
    u.setUsername(username);
    u.setPassword(password);
    u.setEmailaddress(emailadress);
    u.setFirstname(firstname);
    u.setLastname(lastname);
    System.out.println(em + ": Adding course " + u);
    em.persist(u);
    em.flush();
    System.out.println(u.getUser_id());
    return u;
}

public void addStudent(Users2 u2) {
    Student s = new Student();

    s.setUser_id(u2.getUser_id());
    s.setUsername(u2.getUsername());
    s.setLastname(u2.getLastname());
    s.setFirstname(u2.getFirstname());
    s.setPassword(u2.getPassword());
    s.setEmailaddress((u2.getEmailaddress()));

    em.persist(s);
}
```

My method in the Jsf bean looks like this:

```
@Inject
DbStore store;

public String CreateUser(){
    long usrid;

    String username = this.username;
    String password = this.password;
    String emailadress = this.emailaddress;
    String firstname = this.firstname;
    String lastname = this.lastname;
    Users2 u1 = store.addUser(username, password, emailadress, firstname, lastname);
    //System.out.println(usrid);
    String role = this.role;
    if(this.role.equals("Student"))
        store.addStudent(u1);
    return "admin_listcourses.xhtml";

}
```

My entities:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@SecondaryTable(name = "users2",     pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id"))
public class Student {

    /**
     * Created by Elev1 on 2016-08-25.
     *
     */
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="student_student_id_seq",
        sequenceName="student_student_id_seq",
        allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator="seq")
    @Column(name = "student_id", updatable=false)
    private long student_id;

    @Column(table="users2", name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(table="users2", name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(table="users2", name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(table="users2", name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(table="users2", name="emailaddress")
    private String emailaddress;

    @Column(table="users2", name="user_id")

    private  long user_id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="student_course",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="course_id")
    )


    // public List<Course> getCourses() { return courses ; }
    public List<Course> courses;


    //Getters and setters
    public long getStudent_id() {
        return student_id;
    }

    public void setStudent_id(long student_id) {
        this.student_id = student_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmailaddress() {
        return emailaddress;
    }

    public void setEmailaddress(String emailaddress) {
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }
}

package se.lexicon.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity

public class Users2{

    // ***********************
    // **     Attributes    **
    // ***********************

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="users_user_id_seq",
        sequenceName="users_user_id_seq",
        allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator="seq")
    private Long user_id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 64)
    private String username;

    private String password;
    @Column(name = "emailaddress", length = 64)
    private String emailaddress;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date last_login;

    // ************************
    // **     Constructors   **
    // ************************

    //  public User() {

    //     public User(Long user_id) {
    //          this.user_id = user_id;
    //      }

    //      public User(Long user_id, String username, String password, String emailaddress, ??? last_login) {

    //          this.user_id = user_id;
    //          this.username = username;
    //         this.password = password;
    //         this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    //        this.last_login = last_login;
    //}

    // ******************************
    // **    Getters & Setters     **
    // ******************************

    public long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmailaddress() {
        return emailaddress;
    }

    public void setEmailaddress(String emailaddress) {
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }

    public Date getLast_login() {
        return last_login;
    }

    public void setLast_login(Date last_login) {
        this.last_login = last_login;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
//}

}
```

EDIT: My solution. I removed the foregin_key constraint in the student table. I only kept student_id, course_id and user_id in the Student class. I removed all connections between Student and Users2 in the Student class, instead I use methods to get those from the Users2 class if a student_id is given. When a user is created, that is a Student, then a Student is added with the user_id of the user set as the user_id of the Student.

Now this isn't a very good solution, so if some one can solve my original problem I would be happy to accept the solution. But for now my solution will have to do.

Comment: your entity classes would be interesting to spot the problem

Comment: I have updated my question now with my entities.

Answer (score 0):

When you persist a Student instance JPA will also create a row in the `Users2` table with the `user_id` as foreign key to the row in the `Student` table. But there is already a row with the very same ID in the `Users2`, as you persisted a `Users2` instance just before. That's the reason, why you are facing this SQLException.

To me it does not make much sense to use the SecondaryTable-approach here, as there might me Users which are no Students at all, right? But in your current model the Users table is storing a Foreign Key to the Student table..

In this case here it seems to be more appropriate to use inheritance (or maybe some composition) here, instaead of the SecondaryTable-approach.
A Student *is-a* User, so Student may inherit from User. 
You will find a first overview how to define the mapping in this case here:
 https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: How would I go about if I just want to store a foregin key in the student table to the user table (the user_id) but not a foregin key in the usertable to the student table?. It seems a bit messy to use inheritance, because I want users to be able to be a student in one course and a teacher in another.

Comment: I do not see why this might be a problem, but anyhow: It might be sufficient if a/the `Course` entity holds a reference to a  `User` and you name that field `teacher` and a reference to a collections of users named `students`. If you want to find the teahers and or students, you have to look up the courses for the data. Or the student and teacher classes hold a reference to "their" user object. That's what I meant by *compoistion* in my answer. It's not possible to answer what the *best* approach looks like, as this would require much more knowledge about all your use-cases etc..